# I am not able to load machine learning model in my Flask app

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

[image]

I am using Wsgi for the Flask app and Apache server integration.
Can any one help me why i am not able to load my machine learning model.

Comment: What does it mean "i am not able to load"? What exactly goes wrong? How can you tell the model wasn't loaded? Also, please post code as `formatted text`, _not_ images.

Comment: Actually WSGI is not working for my code. So could you please tell me what could be the alternative of WSGI for the flask app and Apache server integration.

Comment: _how exactly_ is it "not working"? How do you know it's not working? Any error messages? Please describe the problem